# timer.Elapsed actions not firing

Tags: c#, asp.net, timer

I have a button that I want to disabled after 4 failed submit attempts. I am using System.Timers timer to count to 15 seconds, then trying to re-enable the button after those 15 seconds.

Here's my code:

```
 if (SessionManager.getRetries > 3)
    {
        Message.Text = "Too many failed attempts. Please retry in 15 seconds.";
        buttonOne.Enabled = false;
        HttpContext.Current.Session["RetryCount"] = 0;
        System.Timers.Timer myTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        myTimer.AutoReset = false;
        myTimer.Interval = 15000;
        myTimer.Enabled = true;
        myTimer.Start();
        myTimer.Elapsed += myTimer_Elapsed;
    }
}

void myTimer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    buttonOne.Enabled = true;
}
```

So far my program will correctly count the # of submissions tried (SessionManager.getRetries). After 4 failed attempts, it will enter this if statement. It then creates the timer, sets the interval, starts it, and knows that the time elapsed. It even goes to the buttonOne.Enabled = true statement, but it doesn't actually enabled my button. (This was observed through the use of breakpoints in visual studio).

Is there something I am missing here? Maybe elapsed events don't work the way I want them to?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try moving the `.Elapsed` hook before the `.Start`

Comment: Just tried it, same behavior :(

Comment: Can you see in the debugger if the timer is firing or not?

Comment: The timer will not fire on an asp.net web page. The timer will start on the server,  but the page request will have ended before the timer fires. You need to do this from Javascript

Comment: But if the button is inside an asp update panel, (both runat server) shouldn't the button be dynamically loaded? Why does the button become disabled when I tell it to then?

Comment: Because with an update panel, the update panel is causing a post back (you can see this with FIddler). With a timer event though, there would have to be a javascript timer to cause a post back. The server can't just say to the client "hey, there was an event". Remember that on the web, flow is one way. From client requesting something to the server serving the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As posted earlier, the problem was not that the events weren't firing, it was that there was no way to show the button as enabled on the client side via the method I was trying previously because the timer only exists server-side.

BUT
I found an easier way than coming up with some sloppy Javascript :)

By using a update panel and asp timer. By placing a asp timer inside of the update panel, and setting the timer to disabled as default, I can then manipulate the timer. Then, when the timer ticks it is automatically updated via the update panel :)

Great code samples here: 
[ASP.NET Timer Event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2800426/asp-net-timer-event)

Answer (score 4):

Timer event should be firing, but it has no way to enable button on HTML page as request is completed by that point.

You should move timer to JavaScript on the page. You still need to keep logic that verifies that retries are not more frequent as it is very easy to bypass JavaScript or any other client side verification.