# Calling a function on timer from a controller in global.asax.cs file

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, timertask

I'm new to C# programming and I cannot figure out how can I trigger a function to be executed every hour.

The function is located in one of my controllers.

The only way I found in the internet is to call it from `Global.asax.cs` file but it doesn't work.

Can somebody help me please with this?

#### The caller

```cs
public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    private static Timer timer;
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        // AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        //WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);

        timer = new System.Timers.Timer(10000);
        var SSSData = new SSSData();

        timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(RedirectToAction("DoPushSend", "Notification", new
        {
            dataSSS = SSSData
        }));
        timer.Interval = 3600000;
        timer.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

#### The callee

```cs
public static void DoPushSend(SSSData dataSSS)
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("sample.com/3/");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    try
    {
        string url = "sample.com/device/";
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        string content = client.DownloadString(url);
        List<string> expoTokens = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(content);

        var expoSDKClient = new PushApiClient();
        var pushTicketReq = new PushTicketRequest()
        {
            PushTo = expoTokens,
            PushBadgeCount = 7,
            PushBody = dataSSS.DESCRIPTION + "[<$>]" + dataSSS.LAT + "[<$>]" + dataSSS.LON + "[<$>]" + dataSSS.MAXRADIUS
        };

        int nowTimeTo = DateTime.Compare(DateTime.Now, dataSSS.TIMETO);
        int nowTimeFrom = DateTime.Compare(DateTime.Now, dataSSS.TIMEFROM);

        if (nowTimeFrom >= 0)
        {
            if (nowTimeTo <= 0)
            {
                var result = expoSDKClient.PushSendAsync(pushTicketReq).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        SSS_Common.Helpers.ErrorHelper.WriteToLog("Notification : ", e);
    }
}
```

Comment: https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/. Although if you want to make absolutely sure the task is executed every hour, then use a windows service.

Comment: I need it through the code, unfortunately

Comment: I think that you have call your DoPushSend function in timer_tick event : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2800426/asp-net-timer-event

Comment: And how should I implement that in my code?